# Why does conjugation by a diagonalizable matrix induce a semisimple automorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

This is a follow up to a question I asked earlier ([Why is conjugation by a diagonal matrix a semisimple automorphism of $\textrm{GL}_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741871/why-is-conjugation-by-a-diagonal-matrix-a-semisimple-automorphism-of-textrmgl)).  Let $G = \textrm{GL}_n$, $s \in G$ a diagonalizable matrix, and let $\phi: G \rightarrow G$ be the automorphism $x \mapsto sxs^{-1}$.  Is it obvious that the comultiplication map $\phi^{\ast}: k[G] \rightarrow k[G]$ is *semisimple*?  I.e. $k[G]$ is the union of finite dimensional $\phi^{\ast}$-invariant subspaces on which $\phi^{\ast}$ acts as a diagonalizable linear transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since left and right multiplication by a semisimple element are so, and they are commutative.

Comment: Thank you, that's right.  I had forgotten the semisimple part of an element $x \in G$ was the unique element $x_s$ such that $(\rho_x)_s = \rho_{x_s}$.